# Return <option> tags from PDO function using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have the following function:

```
function getSystemNames($dbh, $myid) {
    $sql = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT system_name 
    FROM product_systems
    WHERE user_id = :myid
    ORDER BY `system_name` ASC
    ');
    $sql->bindValue('myid', $myid);
    $sql->execute();
    return $sql;
}
;
```

I then have the following code mixed in with my HTML:

```
<select id='group' class='select' name='group'><option value='000'>None</option>
        <?php
        $results = getSystemNames($dbh, $myid);             
        while ($row1 = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){              
          echo "<option value='$row1[system_name]'>$row1[system_name]</option>";
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

I am trying to merge the two so I don't have as much code in my HTML but I haven't been able to figure it out for the past hour and am looking for some help from the community. I have tried to no avail:

```
function getSystemNames($dbh, $myid) {
    $sql = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT system_name 
    FROM product_systems
    WHERE user_id = :myid
    ORDER BY `system_name` ASC
    ');
    $sql->bindValue('myid', $myid);
    $sql->execute();
    while ($row1 = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {                 
        return "<option value='$row1[system_name]'>$row1[system_name]</option>";
    }
}
;
```

Comment: what do you mean by merge the two? can you give any example?

Comment: @itachi I did give the example... I currently call getSystemNames and then run a while loop. Im imagining a better way but when I put the while loop in the function as in my example I get don't get the desired results.

Comment: Downvotes without comments. I always love that. Shall I check with my psychic on what is wrong with my question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getSystemNames($dbh, $myid) {
    $sql = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT system_name 
    FROM product_systems
    WHERE user_id = :myid
    ORDER BY `system_name` ASC
    ');
    $sql->bindValue('myid', $myid);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->fetchAll(); <----- fetch All the data
    return $result;
}
```

It'l return a **multi-dimensional** array. then use a `foreach` in your html part to get the desired output.

P.S. you don't need `;` after `}` here.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean by example in your comments. You mean on the html side. So all I am trying to do is reduce the amount of code I have on the html side. I am hoping to reduce the html code down to simply getSystemNames(); and have the looping occur in the function. I tried to do it in my question but that last function doesn't work. Do you have ideas on how to output the <option> tags with minimal php code in my html?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Put logic and presentation aside. The aim should **be minimise php code inside html part**. not the other way around. It makes debugging and future improvements much easier. I advice you not to use any html part inside the function unless it is necessary. In your case, it isn't necessary.

Comment: Okay itachi, I guess thats the real answer I'm looking for, thanks alot! I am trying to move towards a more OOP approach so I am trying to separate as much PHP out of my HTML as possible. By your advice, I'll stay away from pulling the HTML into my functions for now. Thanks again for your time...

Comment: You are welcome. And i recommend reading about **Model-View-Controller** approach. The model deals with database, the view deals with the presentation and the cotroller handles the requests thus acting as a middle man between the two. It makes code neat, clean, easy to debug.... and easy to modify.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a temporary variable outside the while loop and inside the while loop concatenate it. Then return the temporary variable. and do `echo getSystemNames(..)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not super familiar with php yet. Do you mean to add $temp = array(); before the while loop? And then I'll be able to return $temp; ?? Do you have a code example that can help out myself and others? You get what I want but I'm not sure how its possible to make it happen.

Comment: You sort of have it right, expect $temp would be a string. `$temp = '';` then inside your loop `$temp .= '<select...';` In php `.` is concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for advice tigrang. Based on above comments I am going to stay away from this whole thing for now.